# Actual operator used in chain rule for matrix derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

In case of scalar, chain rule for $Y = f(g(X))$ can be written as
$\frac{dY}{dX} = \frac{dY}{dU}\frac{dU}{dX}$
where $U = g(X)$.

In case of $U$, and $X$ are $M \times N$, $P \times Q$ matrices respectively,
then **$\frac{dY}{dU}$ and $\frac{dU}{dX}$ result in $M \times N$, $MN \times NQ$ matrices respectively.**
Here I see an issue.
The above chain rule doesn't make sense,
because **$M \times N$ matrix and $MN \times NQ$ matrix can be neither multiplied nor applied to dot product because of their sizes**.

What am I missing or misunderstanding?
I guess division of $\frac{dY}{dU}$ and/or multiplication of $\frac{dY}{dU}$ and $\frac{dU}{dX}$
 should be replaced with other operators. But I'm not sure what they're.

Note: I've read many articles regarding derivatives but AFAIK they're introducing the case of vectors($N=1$ and/or $Q=1$).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the double-dot product
$$
\frac{dY}{dX} \;​=\;
​\left(\frac{dY}{dU}\right):\left(\frac{dU}{dX}\right) \\
$$
which can also be written using index notation
$$\frac{dY_{ij}}{dX_{k\ell}} \;​=\;
\sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^N​\left(\frac{dY_{ij}}{dU_{mn}}\right)
\left(\frac{dU_{mn}}{dX_{k\ell}}\right) \\
$$
**NB:** $\;$ All of the gradients above are fourth-order tensors.

Comment: I googled double-dot product and it's likely to be a calculation resulting in a scalar. But as far as I see your equation it works like "element-wise(dYij-wise) double-dot product"?

Comment: The double-dot product between two matrices is a scalar, however the product between two 4th-order _tensors_ is another tensor.

Comment: Then I guess there should be operator to calculate dY from (dY/dU):(dU/dX) and dX. What is gonna be? It's also double dot product? (In case of scalar, dY can be calculated by simple multiplication like dY = (dY/dU)*(dU/dX)*dX. I'd like to know an operator corresponding to the multiplication.)

Comment: Yup, you need another double-dot product: $\;dY = (dY/dU):(dU/dX):dX$

Comment: Thanks greg. I've never seen any resources which introduce this fact. How did you know it? I'd appreciate if you share material which describes this with me if exists.

Comment: Several physics and engineering disciplines (relativity, continuum mechanics, etc) utilize index notation. An upper-level textbook from any of these will contain introductory chapters or appendices which cover this stuff.